# How would I write a SQL query to retrieve closest match to my parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose you have a table (let's call it **RulesTable**) like this in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
Id    |   Type   | SubType1  | SubType2 | Value
  1        A         A1          AA2       10
  5        A         A1          NULL      50
  2        A        NULL         AA3       20
  3        A        NULL         NULL      30
  4      NULL       NULL         NULL      40
```

I will always query for Type, SubType1, SubType2. If one or more is missing then assume it is NULL. The query should always query in the order of Type, SubType1, SubType2 and narrow down the search as it progresses and then match the closest entry. So here are some usage scenarios:

(1) If I query for Type = 'A', SubType1 = 'B', SubType2 = 'C' then since 'B' or 'C' are not found in the table it should use NULLs for them. So I would effectively be looking for Type = 'A', SubType1 = NULL, SubType2 = NULL and I should end up with the value 30 with ID = 3.

(2) If I query for Type = 'A', SubType1 = 'A1', SubType2 = 'C' then subtype2 should = NULL since the value is not in the table and the closest match is Type = 'A', SubType1 = 'A1' and SubType2 = NULL so I should end up with Value = 50.

(3) If I query for Type = 'C', SubType1 = 'C', SubType3 = 'D' then since all of those values are not in my table they all can be replaced with null so effectively I would be searching for Type = NULL, SubType1 = NULL, SubType3 = NULL so I should get the value 40 or Id = 4

So Suppose you have **ParametersAndResultsTable**:

```
MyId | Type |  SubType1 | SubType2 | Id  | Value
  1     A        B           C       ?      ?
  2     A       A1           C       ?      ?
  3     C        C           D       ?      ?
```

So am just looking on ideas how to write a function to update ID/Value in ParametersAndResultsTable(using Type, SubType1, SubType2 as parameters) and given the data of RulesTable using the logic described above. Am thinking maybe to look into a distance calculation but am looking for ideas on how to solve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you want, in order from most accurate to least accurate:

```
SELECT *
FROM RulesTable
WHERE ISNULL([Type], @Param1) = @Param1
AND ISNULL(SubType1, @Param2) = @Param2
AND ISNULL(SubType2, @Param3) = @Param3
ORDER BY [Type] DESC,
SubType1 DESC,
SubType2 DESC
```

Comment: So I guess I would have to change this then to "select top 1 *"? Otherwise, wouldn't this return all sets that are potentially acceptable and not necessarily the closest one?

Comment: Correct, you can include "top 1" in the selection to only get the most accurate record.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION RuleTableFunction (@Type nvarchar(5), @SubType1 nvarchar(5), @SubType2 nvarchar(5))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT 
        Id
        ,Value
    FROM 
        table_name 
    WHERE
        (Type = @Type OR Type IS NULL)
        and (SubType1 = @SubType1 OR SubType1 IS NULL)
        and (SubType2 = @SubType2 OR SubType2 IS NULL)
);
```

To call the function :

```
SELECT * FROM RuleTableFunction ('A','B','C');
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return all acceptable matches and not necessarily the closest one?

Comment: I think it does both in same time, it returns only rows that respect "rules". You should test it to see if that does what you want and if "rules" are respected. For me it is.